# Failed to create virtual object Error in QTP 11

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to create virtual object in QTP 11 but at the end of the selection, getting error message as " Failed to create virtual object "  Can anyone explain how to create virtual objects ?

Answer (score 0):

virtual Objects are created using Virtual Object Manager or New Virtual Object from "Tools" >>

- "Virtual Object" >> "New Virtual Object" and click "Next" Button Map
  the Object against the Class Type and click "Next". Click "Mark
  Object" Button, cross hair cursor would appear and mark the object
  that you would like to map and click "Next". Selecting the parent of
  the Virtual object and click "Next". Name the collection in which you
  would like to store the vitual object and click "Finish".

---

Comment: This procedure I know,I followed the same steps but after clicking Finish button,It says 'Failed to create virtual Object'. I want to know why this is happening?